# My character is broken in pose mode

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

Hat and other objects are joined to the main body.
After adding armature deform with automatic weights my model gets broken.
Head runs away from hat and some parts of model are left behind when I move him in pose mode.

Character in edit mode:

[image]

Character in object/pose mode:

[image]

Moving main bone in pose mode:

[image]

Bones:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it or should I start from stratch?
I have tons of animating to do but I am stuck trying to fix this armature problem.